Dirichlet problem with conformal maps
The problem I am struggling to solve is from Brown and Churchill's Complex Variables and Applications and is intended to be solved using conformal maps:
Derive an expression for steady state temperatures $T(r,\theta)$ (i.e. T is harmonic) in a semicircular plate $r \leq 1, 0 \leq\theta\leq\pi$ with insulated faces if $T=1$ along the radial edge $\theta = 0$ ($0\leq r \leq 1$) and $T=0$ on the rest of the boundary. The expected answer is $T=\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(\frac{1-r}{1+r}\cot(\frac{\theta}{2}))$.
I have tried the following:
We apply $Log(\frac{z-1}{z+1})$ (principal branch of log) on the region to obtain new region in $(u,v)$ plane $\{(u,v):\pi/2 \leq v \leq \pi\}$, where $T(u,\pi)=1 \forall u \leq 0$ and 0 elsewhere on the boundary. However, I don't know how proceed from here and either find a harmonic function or apply additional mappings.
Thanks in advance.
